# Twitterizer: How i can get retweets of a tweet?

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, twitterizer

I am new to twitter and Twitterizer.

I am using Twitterizer API for twitter in C# application.

How i can get retweets of a tweet?

or how i can check if a tweet is retweet or not?

Comment: Refer to the Twitter API docs. I'm sure they have it there.

Answer (score -2):

```
TwitterResponse<TwitterStatusCollection> retweet =
          TwitterStatus.Retweets(tokens, Decimal.Parse(tweet.Id.ToString()));

try
{
    foreach (var ret in entries.ResponseObject)
    { 
    }    
}
catch(NullReferenceException ex)
{
}
```

Comment: Any attempt at an answer should have a description.